# How to make a plain table from a excel with heavy formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, extract

I'm trying to get a plain taible from big presentaion kind excel sheet, with many cells merged together with empty rows, columns as padding borders so it gives presentation look but makes imposiible  to retrieve data with simple script

as follows

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     Logger.log('row: ' + Number(i+1));
    for (var j=0; j<30;j++) {
      if (data[i][j]!='' && data[i][j]!=undefined){
      myArr.push(data[i][j]);
      Logger.log(  data[i][j]); 
      };

    };


  };
};
```

fragment excel source table with merged cells 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID9QY.png

and i want to convert it to something like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtdW4.jpg

Comment: How would you display 14:00-14:40 if there are two values in Column C?

Comment: You must to share something more than two small pictures.

Comment: @Yurij Could you provide a small Sheets document example containing the results you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Please try This:

```
function ConvertData()
{
    var myArr=[];
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var myRow = spreadsheet.getLastRow();
    //begin from row 2
    var beginRow =2;
    var myData = spreadsheet.getRange("E2:G" + myRow).getValues();
    for (i=0;i<(myRow-beginRow);i++)
    {
       myArr.push (myData[i]);
       if (i>0) 
       {
            if (myData[i][0]=="")
            {
                myArr[i][0]=myArr[i-1][0];
            }
            else
            {
                myArr[i][0]=myData[i][0];

            }
       }
    }

    for (i=0;i<(myRow-beginRow);i++)
    {
       Logger.log (myArr[i]);
    }  
}
```

Comment: tnx, for ```myArr[i][0]=myArr[i-1][0];```